Write to a .accdb (Microsoft Access) file that is linked to Sharepoint lists, through Java
I've made a program in Java that can write to AND read from a .accdb database, using the UCanAccess library. It works perfectly... Almost. If the database is just a normal .accdb database on my computer, it has no problem getting used by my application. But I want to link my database to Sharepoint Lists, since I plan on making reports with the data and that requires the data to be in the cloud. I got my .accdb database linked to Sharepoint lists, but once I do that, writing to the .accdb file from my java application no longer works.
I get the following errors if I attempt to write to a .accdb file that is linked to Sharepoint lists:
WARNING:External file C:\Users\ **My name**\Desktop\ *
*My java application**\https:\ **Sharepoint address**.sharepoint.com\sites\\**My Sharepoint Site**;LIST={**List String**};VIEW=;RetrieveIds=Yes;ListDisplayName=; 
does not exist

WARNING:Illegal char <:> at index 5:
 https:\ **<Sharepoint address>**.sharepoint.com\sites\ **My sharepoint site**;LIST={**<List String>**};VIEW=;RetrieveIds=Yes;ListDisplayName=;

Any way I can fix this so I can communicate with the accdb file while they're linked to Sharepoint lists?
